# Java Spring always try to access table 'ismaauser_seq', but I only want it to access to table 'ismaauser'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Here is how I define the table need to be accessed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9f2M.png)

Here is how I configure my WEB app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oTT8.png)

Here is my problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTVR3.png)

I don't know why it always try to access '**_seq'.

I want to figure out where is the suffix come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `GenerationType.AUTO`, Hibernate will choose one of the strategies to generate your id.

> AUTO - either identity column, sequence or table depending on the underlying DB.

So in your case Hibernate uses TABLE (cause MySQL has no sequences feature) and tries to use ismaauser_seq which is not exists.
You can change `GenerationType`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
```

or specify generator:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
@GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
```